# Confirmation that IC with marking CMS69F113D is in fact CMS69F613 (or similar)?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering

As the title implies, I've got an IC marked CMS69F113D and I suspect its similar to, if not a cheap ripoff of, the CMS69F613.
A little context first. I have a laminator, which I'm using to toner transfer onto copper-boards for DIY PCBs. Now I want to crank up the temperature since the toner won't stick to bigger boards so I reverse-engineered the circuit and hit sort of a roadblock with the mentioned IC. I can't find any useful information on the original part number, but I did find a datasheet (in Chinese, unfortunately) for the CMS69F613, an 8-bit MCU from CMSemicon. The IC being an MCU would make sense, since it's connected to some LEDs, an NTC, a TRIAC and a button and I know of little else that could pull that off. Here's the schematic:

[image]

And here's the pinout of the CMS69F613:

[image]

Can anyone confirm or deny what I suspect? Has anyone see that chip marking before?
I can't find similar part numbers on the CMSemicon website, I suspect it's not their newest flagship IC so it might not be listed anymore. Or it's a custom job for the laminator manufacturer.